# how to add _escaped_fragment_ for the urls which contains #! just after the slash?

Tags: backbone.js, seo

In my node + backbone.js application one of the page url will just look like 'http://example.com/#!book1'. How will Google handle this url for crawling?

Do they replace the url to

'example.com/_escaped_fragment_=book1'

or

'example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=book1' ?

Can anyone please guide me?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to support *old* browsers why don't you simple get rid of the `#`?

It's as simple as

`Backbone.history.start({pushState: true})`

Look at https://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/#History

> pushState support exists on a purely opt-in basis in Backbone. Older browsers that don't support pushState will continue to use hash-based URL fragments, and if a hash URL is visited by a pushState-capable browser, it will be transparently upgraded to the true URL. Note that using real URLs requires your web server to be able to correctly render those pages, so back-end changes are required as well. For example, if you have a route of /documents/100, your web server must be able to serve that page, if the browser visits that URL directly. For full search-engine crawlability, it's best to have the server generate the complete HTML for the page ... but if it's a web application, just rendering the same content you would have for the root URL, and filling in the rest with Backbone Views and JavaScript works fine.